# canvas resolution not good

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

i am trying to draw a canvas line on div id "myCanvas" but problem is the line becomes very low resolution and its not shows smooth line. How can i increase that line resolution? And make it smooth line?

js:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      var grd = context.createLinearGradient(100, 150, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      grd.addColorStop(0, '#0132bf');
      grd.addColorStop(1, '#ccd9ff');
      context.fillStyle = grd;
      context.fill();

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.lineTo(-10, 190);
      context.bezierCurveTo(200, -100, 500, 200, 400, 150);

      context.lineWidth = .9;
      context.strokeStyle = '#ccd9ff';
      context.stroke();
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/eadok13s/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving your canvas HTML element width and height attributes that fit your requirements, for example:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600">
```